# Mule ESB Client timeout

Tags: version, upgrade, mule-esb, socket-timeout-exception

I have an esb from which i make a webservice call. The webservice call works well within the organization. We upgraded the Mule ESB version from 3.2.2 to 3.8.5. Both versions work well for us however when vendor calls the web service he get a Socket Time out error.
We have TLSv1.2 enabled in Mule ESB.
The Timeout happens after exactly 20 seconds. However we do not have a timeout set to 20 seconds , for the WS it is set at 60 seconds.
The client uses .net technology. When we use postman to call the WS locally we do not face any issues.
The WS call is simple POST request which accepts xml. Client gets the header information first but then timeout occurs before complete response is received. Is this related to Multipart form data? Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: how do you up the mule server ? via anypoint studio or standalone server

Comment: It is used as a standalone server

Answer (score 0):

By default, the time period is 1000 milliseconds in mule, but you can set another value through the parameter responseTimeout.

```
 <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://test.com/ws" method="post" exchange-pattern="request-response" responseTimeout="5000"/>
```

But Ideally for Webservice consuming,
When you configure the Webservice Consumer connector ,goto-->References-->Http Configuration reference-->Click Edit-->Other settings-->Response Time out as 60000 (which is 60 seconds) .Then your esb call can wait till 60 seconds .Depends on response time you can either increase or decrease time out .Hope this helps..

Comment: We are trying with following-

Comment: <http:listener config-ref="httpListenerConfig" path="*" doc:name="HTTP" parseRequest="false" />                                                            We want to see if after this change client can access the ESB. We believe this is an issue with Multipart form data that is why only the header info is received and complete response is not received by client. Also , looked into the followingWanted to use HttpMuleMessageFactory which is used prior to Mule ESB 3.4.x

Comment: Still getting following error on client end-                           java.net.SocketException: Connection reset                      Connection lost.                                                         Response has 0 lines                                               Connection lost while reading header.

Comment: After the configuration, looks like the client timeout is happening immediately. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Mule to version 3.8 you also should port the flow to the new components. Replace the `http:outbound-endpoint` by using `http:request`. Configure the `responseTimeout` property. I had situations like these before. Try to change the `parseResponse` or/and `requestStreamingMode`. Depending on the WS, Mule can run into a wait.

```
<http:request-config name="requestConfig" ... responseTimeout="120000"  />

<http:request path="/api/v1/orders" method="POST" config-ref="requestConfig">
   <!-- configure the elements you need -->
</http:request>
```

By the way, Mule also has a component for Webservice (SOAP) consumption. If you need help by migration from Mule 3.3 (or other) to any version, just let me know.